# Can markers changes undo through history/revert to original?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm a contributor to a [food foraging map](https://maps.google.co.nz/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=105452119347441306027.00046e04e65dedbbc7079) and found that many markers are in the ocean. I then also noticed that I had an undo at the top of gmaps and realised I'd moved 5 trees trying to get to my area.

Is it possible to see marker/map history at maps.google.com? Is it possible to revert markers to original position?

I'm completely open to programming this using the api if necessary - surely this information is somewhere...